# Laravel mailables dynamic view treat as blade

Tags: php, laravel

does it possible to do:

Create Mailable class in my package and use it to `Mail::send(new MyMaiable($config))`

In my config will also html template saved in database.

My question is does it any way to use this html string as blade template

I mean
`{{$var}}` will replace without manually `str_replace` or `preg_replace_all`
but by `->with([])` method.

Environment

- php 5.6
- Laravel 5.4

Thanks in advance for any hints.

Comment: Arguments to `Mail::send` are not what you want them to be.

Comment: probably you are right but what you suggest `getViewFactory `?

Comment: I don't understand the problem and I don;t know what is `getViewFactory`

Comment: Try https://github.com/TerrePorter/StringBladeCompiler package

Answer (score -1):

Why are you storing the html template in your database? Save the template in your resources->emails folder as a blade template and call it in the mailable class like this:

```
public function build()
{
    return $this->from('YOUR_FROM_EMAIL')
        ->view('emails.TEMPLATE_NAME');
}
```

Comment: My users create it by interface this is reason why I decided to storing in DB.
What I look at what is possible probably better way is keep it as views in storage folder and load standard way